# Is there any way to automate the purchase order receiving if PO item is cross referenced to a Job In infor syteline?

Tags: erp

Currently we are using *Infor Syteline ERP Version 9*.

Is there any way to automate the Job material transaction process while receiving the PO when the PO item is cross reference to a Job?

When I do the *Purchase order* receiving process for the items which are cross referenced to a job its navigating to the job material transaction form to process the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

We can by pass the job material transaction processing section by making modification in the receiving form scripts, but to automate the process we would need to create stored procedure to bypass the process.